# How do I get container id from AWS CDK Mediastore?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, mediastore

How do I get container id from AWS CDK Mediastore?
It is being used as below code.

```
const mediaStoreContainer = new mediastore.CfnContainer(this, 'mediaStoreContainer', {
      containerName: 'MediaStoreContainer',
      accessLoggingEnabled: true,
})
```

I've tried many ways, but I can't find it.

```
mediaStoreContainer.getAtt(mediaStoreContainer.attrEndpoint)...
```

Please tell me how I can get it.

Comment: What exactly is a container ID?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, any time you have to use a Cfn function in CDK, this indicates that that resource/service/thing is not fully hooked into the cdk libraries. these Cfn functions simply are basic parsers that output a json structure for the cloudformation template. getAtt may not even be hooked into all the attributes available to a given item, and most of the time the Cfn versions of a construct can't even be passed to other constructs that would use them (such as having a Role created and passing that role to a Lambda to use)

getAtt just mimics the yaml macro function !getAttr and so can only retrieve what is available from the cloudformation entry for that resource

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-mediastore-container.html - this page indicates its just Endpoint - i believe all you need to use is `endpoint = mediaStorecontainer.getAtt("Endpoint")`